# symfony2 serialized data replace error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, serialization, replace

So I am trying to move a live installation onto my localhost. I have a great deal of images in my user data, images that have been uploaded and inserted into posts.

The problem is that on the live server image routes are

```
/uploads/images/...
```

while on the localhost environment it will be

```
/mysite/web/uploads/images/...
```

So I gave it a shot using the searchreplacedb2.php script found here (https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ I used v2.1.0 stable) it is the one recommended for moving a wordpress installation, and I thought the serialization of data in the mySql should work the same way on a WP as in a Sym2 app.

But perhaps not, since I get the following error from Sym2 when it attempts to read form that table I did the search/replace on:

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 1672 of 1953 bytes in /Users/acr/Documents/www/cloudsign/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ArrayType.php line 48
```

Here is a sample of the serialized data I have performed the replace on:

```
a:6:{i:0;s:11:"transparent";i:3;s:6:"repeat";i:4;s:4:"left";i:5;s:3:"top";i:6;s:1707:"<div id="object_01" class="object_image lockedAspectRatio ui-draggable ui-resizable" namn="object_01" style="height:1036.5599999427795px;width:1635.5599999427795px;left:-1.994384765625px;top:-15px;position:absolute;"><img class="object_inner" src="/cloudsign/web/uploads/images/20/c274edd7f10f5d34157108658d9e7e6eebf16bb4.jpeg" alt="c274edd7f10f5d34157108658d9e7e6eebf16bb4" /><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index:1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index:1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index:1000;"></div></div><div id="object_02" class="object_textbox" namn="object_02" style="z-index:2;font-family:Arial;left:940.9950561523438px;top:84.98873901367188px;position:absolute;width:493.55999994277954px;height:77.55999994277954px;"><div class="object_inner" style="border:0px solid rgb(0,0,0);background-color:rgb(163,178,240);color:rgb(255,255,255);font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:44px;line-height:66px;text-align:center;">Vinter Kampanj!</div></div><div id="object_03" class="object_textbox" namn="object_03" style="z-index:3;font-family:Arial;left:917px;top:215px;position:absolute;width:549.5599999427795px;height:625.5599999427795px;"><div class="object_inner" style="border:0px solid rgb(0,0,0);color:rgb(0,0,0);text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:44px;line-height:66px;border-top-left-radius:15px;border-top-right-radius:15px;border-bottom-right-radius:15px;border-bottom-left-radius:15px;">Missa inte vår stora vinter rea med upp till 70% rabatt! <br /><br /><br />Många stora märken som North Face, Peak<br />Adidas, Columbia, Burton m.m.</div></div>";i:7;s:8:"original";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Doctrine Lifecycle callbacks to change that path while in development, instead of changing the database content. My opinion is that you could use `@PostLoad` to achieve what you want in a more elegant way.

Reference: [Doctrine Lifecycle Callbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: Do you mean to perform the string replacement on the contents of the serialized array live while running the app?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to leave the database content as is and `str_replace` the path on the fly, while in development. Do you think will not work ?